# Symfony and Postgres - connection with non public schema

Tags: postgresql, symfony-3.4

I have a problem configuring symfony 3.4 with postgres. Exactly when the main scheme is not public.
Symfony works and connects to the database without errors, but that's it. Application does not, because public schema does not exist.
Can someone help me how to connect to a specific schema?

Comment: You can change the `search_path` for the database user `alter user ... set search_path = ...;` then this is independent of the application or the way you connect

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You can direct me to the file? This variable appears in several postgres related files in framework

Comment: Not a file. You change the "setup" of the _database_ user through a SQL command. See [the Postgres manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) for details

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's working. I don't know if your answer was crucial, but I did it first. It didn't work by itself. 
But after adding the schema name to @ORM\Table, ... yes :)